# Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast

Tags: apache-pig

I wanted to do the sum of a column which contains long type numbers.
I tried many possible ways but still the cast error is not getting resolved.

My pig code:

```
raw_ds = LOAD '/tmp/bimallik/data/part-r-00098' using PigStorage(',')  AS (
    d1:chararray, d2:chararray, d3:chararray, d4:chararray, d5:chararray,
    d6:chararray, d7:chararray, d8:chararray, d9:chararray );

parsed_ds = FOREACH raw_ds GENERATE d8  as inBytes:long, d9  as outBytes:long;

X = FOREACH parsed_ds GENERATE (long)SUM(parsed_ds.inBytes) AS inBytes;
dump X;
```

Error snapshot:

> 2015-11-20 02:16:26,631 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045:
>    Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or          none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
>   Details at logfile: /users/bimallik/pig_1448014584395.log
>   2015-11-20 02:17:03,629 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 50% complet

Comment: show sample input from part-r-00098 file

Comment: Did you check this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405267/error-1045-on-sum-function-in-pig-latin-with-an-int

Answer (score 2):

@ManjunathBallur Thanks for the input. 
I changed my code as below now

```
<..same as before ...>
A = GROUP parsed_ds by inBytes;
X = FOREACH A GENERATE SUM(parsed_ds.inBytes) as h;
DUMP X;
```

Now A is generating a bag of common inBytes and X is giving sum of each bag's inBytes's summation which is again consisting of multiple rows where as I need one single summation value.

Answer (score 0):

In local mode I was getting the same issue (`pig -x local`).

I have tried all the solutions available on the internet but noting seems to be working for me.

I toggled my PIG from local to the `mapreduce` mode and tried the solution. It worked.

In `mapreduce` mode all the solutions seem to be working.

Comment: This requires a running Hadoop/YARN cluster, though, which is not a requirement for Pig